# How to call and get data form store procedure?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

Please advise me how to call and get data from store procedure?

```
private void GetPatient(string sPatient)
    {
        string connString = "Server = XXX.X.X.XXX; Database = XXX; UID = XXXX; Password = XXXX";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        MySqlDataAdapter da;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand("getPerson_Search", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sPatient", sPatient);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@tFullName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 64);
        cmd.Parameters["@tFullName"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@tHN", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 9);
        cmd.Parameters["@tHN"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@tCid", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 13);
        cmd.Parameters["@tCid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.DataBinding();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ข้อผิดพลาด");

        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return "OK.";
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect if your program is even compiling. You are returning a string from `void` function.

Comment: "there were build errors" - so: fix those first? nothing will work until it compiles; the second one seems relevant to this - but the rest are unrelated

Answer (score 1):

Broadly, you're along the right lines. There are some build errors that are blocking you, such as trying to return a `string` from a `void` method that need fixing, but that is unrelated to the question. You have most of the ADO.NET stuff OK-ish. There are some "nits" such as using `using` around the disposable objects (`conn`, `cmd`, etc).

Note that `@tFullName` doesn't seem to be populated by your SQL, so I doubt that parameter will work as you expect. It looks like you're thinking of the *columns* as though they are *out parameters*, in which case: you simply don't need those parameters at all. Columns come back via the data-reader that (in this case) the data-adapter is working with. Frankly, I would advocate *against* using `DataTable` in most scenarios (the main exception being things like ad-hoc report queries where the schema cannot be reasonably known) - instead moving to a `List<SomeType>` model (or similar). There are tools like "dapper" that would help with that, making your code just something like:

```
using(var conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
    var people = conn.Query<Person>("getPerson_Search", new { sPatient },
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).AsList();
    peopleGrid.DataSource = people;
}
```

(where `class Person` has properties that match the columns coming from your query)